# Count How Many Times a Value Appears Php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, count, logic

i have a foreach and the code below returns to me the values (int) that you can see from Screenshot 1

```
foreach ($getMatches->participants as $data) {

  $count = ($data->id);
  

  echo '<pre id="json">'; var_dump($count); echo '</pre>';
   
  }
```

[image: Screen shot 1]

So,  i want to count how many times the same value appears.
In this case : Value 98 : 2 times ; Value 120: 3 times , etc.

I've tried to convert my $count variable to an array and use array_count_values like the code below , but with no success. As you can see in screenshot 2 the value 98 is returning only 1 instead of 2, the value 120 is returning only 1 instead of 3 , etc

```
  foreach ($getMatches->participants as $data) {

  $count = array($data->id);
  

  echo '<pre id="json">'; var_dump(array_count_values($count)); echo '</pre>';
   
  }
```

[image: Screen shot 2]

Comment: is `$getMatches->participants` a laravel collection object?

Comment: is coming from an api  $getMatches = $api->getMatch($data->ids);

Comment: Do you mean that each $data->id is an array, since you are trying to use array_count_values inside the foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_count_values`, enjoy :-)

```
$array = array(12,43,66,21,56,43,43,78,78,100,43,43,43,21);
//basically we get the same array
foreach ($array as $data) {

  $count[] = $data;
}   
$vals = array_count_values($count);
print_r($vals);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [12] => 1
    [43] => 6
    [66] => 1
    [21] => 2
    [56] => 1
    [78] => 2
    [100] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the desired results probably as you are doing everything within the foreach loop

Let's try with Laravel collections

```php
$items = collect([]);

foreach ($getMatches->participants as $data) {
    $items->push($data->id);   
}

dd($items->countBy()->all());
```

Comment: this works for me but how can i print without the dd ? can i echo ?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve, you can use `dump()` instead of dd which won't stop the execution.

Comment: i'm trying to show this inside a html table

Comment: For that you can loop over the array `@foreach($items as $key => $value)<p> {{ $key }} : {{ $value }}</p>@endforeach`

Answer (score 0):

If `$getMatches->participants` is an array of objects, you should to first iterate a loop over that and sum of repeats.

```
$count = [];
foreach ($getMatches->participants as $data)
{
    if (isset($count[$data->id]))
    {
        $count[$data->id] = $count[$data->id] + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $count[$data->id] = 1;
    }
}
```

Then in other loop show the result

```
echo '<pre id="json">';
foreach ($count as $key => $data)
{
    echo $key . ' repeated ' . $data . ' times'. PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score -1):

`array_count_values` does exactly what you need, there is no need for another loop.

```
$array = [25,943,943,21,9,25,943,1,2,4];
$counts = array_count_values($array);
```

Result is:

```
[
   25 => 2,
   943 => 3,
   21 => 1,
   9 => 1,
   1 => 1,
   2 => 1,
   4 => 1,
]
```